# CUDA can't find GPU on mac

Tags: macos, python-3.x, cuda, tensorflow, gpu

A couple days ago I have managed to get CUDA working with tensorflow on my mac with a GeForce GTX 780M. However today I've noticed it is no longer working. I'm not sure what has changed but I've verified that the libraries (especially cudann) are still properly installed.

Neither restarting nor reinstalling tensorflow helped (I installed tensorflow from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-0.12.1-py3-none-any.whl) Here's the output from running the mnist example from the tensorflow website:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.1.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.dylib locally
Extracting MNIST_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:509] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:158] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: Net-iMac-3.local
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:165] hostname: Net-iMac-3.local
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] libcuda reported version is: 310.42.25
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:193] kernel reported version is: Invalid argument: expected %d.%d or %d.%d.%d form for driver version; got ""
step 0, training accuracy 0.06
```

Here's the output of `nvcc -V`:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Oct_30_22:18:43_CDT_2016
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.54
```

Output of: `ls -l /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcud*`

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mik   admin    33B Jan  7 16:29 /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcuda.1.dylib -> /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcuda.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel    13K Nov  3 19:39 /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcuda.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel    45B Nov  3 19:40 /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcudadevrt.a -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib/libcudadevrt.a
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel    50B Nov  3 19:40 /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcudart.8.0.dylib -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib/libcudart.8.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel    46B Nov  3 19:40 /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcudart.dylib -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib/libcudart.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel    49B Nov  3 19:40 /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcudart_static.a -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib/libcudart_static.a
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 mik   staff    74M Jul 27 09:18 /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcudnn.5.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 mik   staff    16B Jul 27 09:21 /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcudnn.dylib -> libcudnn.5.dylib
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mik   staff    63M Jul 27 09:18 /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcudnn_static.a
```

I have tried reinstalling the drivers, installing old ones and none of it helped

According to https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/issues/38 I did `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1` to prevent memory issues when running tensorflow. If I then run `./deviceQuery` it fails to find the gpu:

```
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/samples/bin/x86_64/darwin/release/deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 38
-> no CUDA-capable device is detected
Result = FAIL
```

However if I run `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0` then running `./deviceQuery` gives:

```
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/samples/bin/x86_64/darwin/release/deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 780M"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          8.0 / 8.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    3.0
  Total amount of global memory:                 4096 MBytes (4294508544 bytes)
  ( 8) Multiprocessors, (192) CUDA Cores/MP:     1536 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            784 MHz (0.78 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             2500 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              256-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 524288 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 2 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA
```

Comment: Verify your CUDA install using the procedures given in the CUDA MaOS install guide.

Comment: running `./deviceQuery` fails to find the gpu

Comment: Could this be caused by my gpu being relatively old compared to cuda 8.0?

Comment: GTX780M is fully supported by CUDA 8.0.  It certainly seems like your CUDA install is broken.  Perhaps you should reinstall CUDA or keep working on your system until CUDA can pass simple verification tests, rather than wondering why tensorflow is not working.

Comment: I've done some more testing and something strange is happening. (See edited post). Although at this point its probably me not being familiar with cuda's environment variables

Comment: In the failing case, do `echo $CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`  Nevermind.  Yes, if you do `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1` and you only have 1 GPU in your system, that will cause CUDA to become non-functional.  I'm not sure why you would do that.  That environment variable is documented [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#env-vars).

Comment: Yes ... in retrospect I should have checked the documentation. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1" means that Cuda only sees gpu_1 on your machine. Do you have two GPUs? What does "nvidia-smi" show?

In general, if you want to use "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES", make sure you point to a GPU that you want to use.